# C# Regular Expression for email validation in DataAnnotations - Double backslash

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-2

Saw this code for regular expression validation of an email address via data annotations.

I Can't work out the purpose of the double backslash.

To me it's saying there must be a backslash in the email - but I know that this isn't what it is doing!!!

```
 [RegularExpression(".+\\@.+\\..+",   ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid email")]
```

Comment: try [this one](http://lesson8.blogspot.com/2013/03/email-regular-expression-mvc-c.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The backslash is an escape character both in C# and in a regex. So, in C#, `"\\"` equals to a single backslash. The resulting backslash is then used to escape the `.`, which is a metacharacter and therefore must be escaped. I don't know why the `@` is escaped however.

Answer (score 4):

For MVC2 Pattern

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class EmailValidationAttribute: RegularExpressionAttribute
{    
    public EmailValidationAttribute() : base(@"^([\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+\.)*[\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+@((((([a-zA-Z0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,62}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1})|[a-zA-Z])\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6})|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(\:\d{1,5})?)$")
    {

    }
}
```

**And then use**

```
[EmailValidation(ErrorMessage="Not a valid Email Address")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

This will work perfectly..

Comment: I tried this solution and it works fine for server-side validation.  However, EmailValidationAttribute won't wire up for client-side validation.  Just using RegularExpressionAttribte with the regular expression you provider works great on the client-side as well as server-side though.  Something like this:  [RegularExpression(@"^([\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+\.)*[\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+@((((([a-zA-Z0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,62}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1})|[a-zA-Z])\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6})|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(\:\d{1,5})?)$", ErrorMessage = "Email address must be a valid email address.")]

Answer (score 2):

Certain characters have special meaning when escaped in a regular expression. For instance \d means a number.

In C# the backslash has a similar function. For instance \n means newline. In order to get a literal backslash in C# you must escape it...with a backslash. Two together is the same as a literal backslash.

C# has a way of denoting a string as literal so backslash characters are not used - prepend the string with @.

Answer (score 0):

Double-backslash are mandatory because backslash is an Escape character in C#. An alternative could be `@".+\@.+\..+"`